# LINQ query to return all records matching all subquery criteria

Tags: linq, entity-framework

This is probably very simple and i am suffering from "firday afternoon syndrome" but i am having a bit of trouble building a linq expression.

I have the following entities - Rooms, RoomsPeople, and PersonType.

I am trying to return all the rooms that contain teachers and students (types of people)

so my queries are along the lines of

```
context.Rooms.Where(x => x.RoomsPeople.Any(b => (((b.PersonTypeID== 1) && (b.PersonTypeID== 2)) && (b.PersonTypeID== 3)))).ToList<Rooms>();
```

Reading this literally, it appear it should do what i want..."Return  rooms where the RoomsPeople contain any of the personTypes"

Can anybody help?

Comment: "i am having a bit of trouble." You should describe what's going wrong. Is it not compiling? Are you not getting the list you expect to get?

Comment: a single value (PersonTypeId) cannot be at the same 1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
context.Rooms
    .Where(x => 
        x.RoomsPeople.Any(b => b.PersonTypeID == 1) &&
        x.RoomsPeople.Any(b => b.PersonTypeID == 2) &&
        x.RoomsPeople.Any(b => b.PersonTypeID == 3)
    )
    .ToList<Rooms>();
```

If you look at your original code, you'll notice that you have this predicate:

```
(((b.PersonTypeID== 1) && (b.PersonTypeID== 2)) && (b.PersonTypeID== 3)))
```

First of all, this can be simplified to:

```
b.PersonTypeID == 1 && b.PersonTypeID == 2 && b.PersonTypeID == 3
```

Now it should be clear why your code didn't work.  It's not possible for a single `PersonTypeID` to be simultaneously multiple different values (1, 2, *and* 3)

Thus the solution is to use the `.Any` predicate multiple times -- once for each person type you want to check against.

Comment: Thank you Kirk, it great explanation. It does make more sense now.